# Микро и макрозадачи. Event loop

Tags: javascript, event-loop

Согласно документации код выполняется по следующим правилам:

1. Выбрать и исполнить старейшую задачу из очереди макрозадач.
2. Исполнить все микрозадачи:
3. Пока очередь микрозадач не пуста:

   - Выбрать из очереди и исполнить старейшую микрозадачу
4. Отрисовать изменения страницы, если они есть.
5. Если очередь макрозадач пуста – подождать, пока появится макрозадача.
6. Перейти к шагу 1.

```
setTimeout(function timeout() {
    console.log('Таймаут');
}, 0);

let p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('Создание промиса');
    resolve();
});

p.then(function(){
    console.log('Обработка промиса');
});

console.log('Конец скрипта');
```

Результатом будет:

```
Создание промиса
Конец скрипта
Обработка промиса
Таймаут
```

Если settimeout - это макротаска, то почему она не выполнилась до обработки промиса, т.е:

```
Создание промиса
Конец скрипта
Таймаут
Обработка промиса
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout` - выполнился и *запланировал новую* большую задачу.

Переход к ее выполнению осуществляется, когда выполнились все маленькие задачки, созданные, внутри текущей большой.

Comment: что означает setTimeout - выполнился ?

Comment: @twinpig, это значит что выполнилась функция `setTimeout` и запланировала выполнение переданного ей коллбэка

Comment: @twinpig, собственно основная ошибка у тебя в терминологии: _Если settimeout - это макротаска_ - это неверно. `setTimeout` - **планирует** новую макротаску, а не сразу начинает ее выполнять

Comment: спасибо, теперь понятно)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Макрозадача. Попадает в очередь макрозадач.
// Приоритет всегда отдается микрозадачам, то есть сначала 
// выполняются все микрозадачи, а потом макро.
setTimeout(function timeout() {
    console.log('Таймаут');
}, 0);

// Микрозадача (до resolve) не попадает в очередь микрозадач
let p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('Создание промиса');
resolve();
});

// Попадает в очередь микрозадач после Resolve
p.then(function(){
    console.log('Обработка промиса');
});

// Не попадает в очередь и выводится сразу
console.log('Конец скрипта');
```